# How to center this header?

Tags: html, css, gridview, styles, center

I'm trying to center my header link(Product Name), but when I use `text-align : center`, `margin:auto` etc, it still doesn't move. Would anyone please point me toward the right direction?

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58hmJ/3/) for reference.

Html code:

```
<a href="#"><img src='jpg' alt='Image' /></a>
 <h3>
 <a href="%PRODUCT_URL%">Product Name</a>
 </h3>
```

CSS:

```
.prod-box h3 a{
    text-decoration: none;
    width:140px;
    text-align : center ;
    margin: 5px 0;
    color:#888;
    font: italic normal 14px georgia;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the styles to the `h3`, not the `a`.

```
.prod-box h3
```

or make the `a` `display: block;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
.prod-box h3{
    text-decoration: none;
    width:140px;
    text-align : center ;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color:#888;
    font: italic normal 14px georgia;
    font-style: italic;
```

}